# Subview from UITableViewCell doesn't refresh right away after update of underlying table

Tags: ios, uitableview, asynchronous, addsubview

I've been battling with this issue for several days. I'm not an Obj-C expert but so far I was able to find my way until now :)

Basically I update a property of my tableViewController but it only updates the cell several seconds after the property was updated. I suspect an issue with cells being recycled but I thought I prevented that in my code.

As a note: **[event updateThumbs]** is a method that create a subview after downloading many thumbnails and combining them to create multiple buttons.

here is my code. Thanks for any help:

```
- (UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"EventCell"];
//self.feedEvents is an NSMutableArray containing list of events
Event *event = [self.feedEvents objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
event.delegate = self;

if (event.thumbsView == nil) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        // The following method builds a view by combining subviews of buttons with thumbnails
        // downloaded from back end.
        [event updateThumbs];
        NSLog(@"loaded %@ for cell %ld",event.description,(long)indexPath.section);
        [self.feedEvents replaceObjectAtIndex:indexPath.section withObject:event];
    });
}
if (cell.contentView.subviews.count > 0) {
    [cell.contentView.subviews[0] removeFromSuperview];
}

if (event) {
    [cell.contentView addSubview:event.thumbsView];
}

return cell;}
```

*********** UPDATE  ********

I'm moving a bit forward I think. I changed the structure of the code by doing the a-sync work outside of the cellForRowAtIndex. It now happens in the method that calls the backend to populate the underlying property. But still, it doesn't work. The cells is updated only 4 to 6 seconds after the data is loaded. Here is what I do now:

```
- (UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

     UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"EventCell"];
     //self.feedEvents is an NSMutableArray containing list of events
     Event *event = [self.feedEvents objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
     event.delegate = self;

     if (cell.contentView.subviews.count > 0) {
         [cell.contentView.subviews[0] removeFromSuperview];
     }

     if (event) {
         [cell.contentView addSubview:event.thumbsView];
     }

     return cell;
}
```

and in the call to the back-end in the same Class

```
  [self.feedEvents enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {

        Event *event = (Event *) obj;

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT,0), ^{
            //a-sync work
            [event updateThumbs];

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [self.feedEvents replaceObjectAtIndex:idx withObject:event];
                [self.tableView reloadData];
            });
        });

    }];
```